# The type Entity is deprecated in Eclipse

Tags: java, hibernate

When I typing @Entity in my java file, I am getting a warning is like The type Entity is deprecated in Eclipse. I want to know Why I am getting this problem. Can anyone help me. I am using Eclipse 3.8 version.